# Rx.js: check sequence of items asynchronously with promise and take until true is returned

Tags: promise, rxjs

I'm very new to Rx. I have an array of usernames and I'm testing them against a db until I get to one which doesn't exist (a free one). The db call gives me a promise.

How can I implement it with rx(.js)?

The code I implemented until now is:

the usernames stream

```
var usernamesStream = Rx.Observable.from(['user1','user2','user3'])
```

the db query method

```
var checkUsernameIsFree = function (username) {
  return db.users.find({username:username}).toArray().then(function(users) {
    return users.length == 0
  })
}
```

I guess I should create a stream by using `.fromPromise` on the promise. How can I implement that and join the 2 streams so that `subscribe` gets called only with the first free username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concatMap`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/concatmap.md) to preserve the order of your requests, also it will accept promises implicitly:

```
var usernames = Rx.Observable.from(['user1','user2','user3']);

//Preserve the order of the requests
var subscription = usernames.concatMap(function(name) {
           return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(db.users.find({username:name}).toArray())
                               .filter(function(x) { return x.length == 0; })
                               .map(function() {return name; });
          })
         .first()
         .subscribe(
           function(availableUserName){
             /*Only gets called once*/
           },
           function(e){ 
             /*Will get raised if no names were found or
               there was a problem accessing the database*/
          });
```

A couple things that will change depending on your requirements:

1. If no result is not an error, you should use [`.firstOrDefault()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/firstordefault.md) or [`.filter().take(1)`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/where.md) instead.
2. In the above solution, `concatMap` will probably kick off database requests on all the names, and simply preserve the order of the responses. If you want to delay the execution of the the db request until the previous finished you should wrap `db.users.find` with `startAsync`:

---

```
return Rx.Observable.startAsync(function() { 
  return db.users.find({username : name}).toArray();
});
```

**Edit 1**

Fixed a bug in the previous code that didn't pass the name value to the final subscriber.

Comment: I just tested it and it looks like it's not passing the usernames through, but the concatMap promise results instead. I mean `availableUserName` is actually `true` and not the corresponding value from the `usernames` stream.

Comment: You are very correct. I updated my example (and tested it this time). Hopefully that will work now.

Comment: Ok. This one is working. I'm accepting the answer. I wonder if there's a way to ensure each call to db is successful and receives a response (no connection errors) before attempting the next query.

Comment: Like I said at the bottom, if you make use of `startAsync` to wrap the call to the database, it will delay the execution until the previous one finishes, and the semantics of RxJS error handling mean that any errors in any of the sequences will be delivered to the final `subscribe` method.